# Transpose dataframe columns generated from parsed XML in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, transpose

As one of the problem statement I am working on parsing XML data using PySpark.

Below is the sample data -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<component>Engineering

  <headers>
    <header>
      <name>Date</name>
      <value>05/05/2021 14:50:03</value>
    </header>
    <header>
      <name>StdName</name>
      <value>CoreEngineering</value>
    </header>
    <header>
      <name>ID</name>
      <value>12432AA</value>
    </header>
    <header>
      <name>DeviceType</name>
      <value>EngineGear</value>
    </header>
  </headers>
  
   <headers>
    <header>
      <name>Date</name>
      <value>05/05/2021 14:59:13</value>
    </header>
    <header>
      <name>StdName</name>
      <value>CoreEngineering</value>
    </header>
    <header>
      <name>ID</name>
      <value>98344AA</value>
    </header>
    <header>
      <name>DeviceType</name>
      <value>EngineExhaust</value>
    </header>
  </headers>
  
  
 </component>
```

While parsing this xml file in databricks using pyspark I am using below logic -

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df = spark.read \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml") \
    .option("rootTag", "headers") \
    .option("rowTag", "header") \
    .load("/mnt/test/sourcedata/sample.xml") \
    .withColumn("processeddatetime",unix_timestamp(lit(timestamp),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').cast("timestamp"))
```

And the output received is :

[image]

However, wondering how I can transpose the data received since that is required for further data transformations.
Required dataset should have the schema like below-

[image]

How to transpose this data to above expected schema in PySpark?

Comment: please replace screenshots with text data so that users can replicate your scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping the data after the xml file has been read will be difficult as the data contains no grouping criterium that indicated with rows belong together.

Instead using `component` as `rootTag` and and `headers` as `rowTag` you get the required grouping of the rows. Within a row, you can use [map_from_entries](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.map_from_entries.html) to separate the entries from each other and then [select](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.selectExpr.html) the individual elements of the map as required:

```python
df = spark.read \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml") \
    .option("rootTag", "component") \
    .option("rowTag", "headers") \
    .load("test.xml") \
    .withColumn("tmp", F.map_from_entries("header")) \
    .selectExpr("'Engineering' as Component", 
          "tmp['Date'] as Date", 
          "tmp['StdName'] as StdName", 
          "tmp['ID'] as ID", 
          "tmp['DeviceType'] as DeviceType") \
    .withColumn("processeddatetime",F.unix_timestamp(F.lit(timestamp),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').cast("timestamp")) \
```

The value of the column `Component` is hard coded here as you cannot get a value from the root tag element in Spark xml.

Comment: Perfect! werner, appreciate your thoughts here.